# Is there a generator version of `sample` in Python?

Tags: python, generator, netlogo

NetLogo argues that one of its important features is that it activates agents from an agentset in pseudo-random order. If one wanted to do something similar in Python one might do the following.

```
from random import sample
for agent in sample(agentset, len(agentset)): 
    < do something with agent >
```

I believe that would work fine. The problem is that `sample` returns a list. If `agentset` is large, one is essentially duplicating it. (I don't want to use `shuffle` or `pop` since these modify the original agentset.)

Ideally, I would like a version of `sample` that acts as a generator and `yield`s values when requested.  Is there such a function? If not, any thoughts about how to write one--without either modifying the original set or duplicating it?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you want to avail yourself of the `shuffle` method in your solution.

Comment: The difficulty is that you need to keep track of what's left or what you've already used, both of which essentially require keeping track of a data structure the size of the input.

Comment: Have you looked at MESA or GAMA? These both support ABM in Python so must have solved the problem already.

Comment: Although I haven't scoured the documentation carefully, none of the ABM systems I know of (Repast, MASON, MESA, GAMA, and others) explicitly claim this capability.

Comment: In fact, AFIK, even NetLogo doesn't claim to provide this capability without replicating the agentset or equivalent.

Comment: BTW, I believe that MESA is written in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithms underlying `sample` require memory proportional to the size of the sample. (One algorithm is rejection sampling, and the other is a partial shuffle.) Neither can do what you're looking for.

What you're looking for requires different techniques, such as [format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). A format-preserving cipher is essentially a keyed bijection from [0, n) to [0, n) (or equivalently, from any finite set to itself). Using format-preserving encryption, your generator would look like (pseudocode)

```
def shuffle_generator(sequence):
    key = get_random_key()
    cipher = FormatPreservingCipher(key, len(sequence))
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        yield sequence[cipher.encrypt(i)]
```

This would be a lot slower than a traditional shuffle, but it would achieve your stated goal.

I am not aware of any good format-preserving encryption libraries for Python. (`pyffx` exists, but testing shows that [either it's terrible, or it has severe limitations that aren't clearly documented](https://github.com/emulbreh/pyffx/issues/10). Either way, it doesn't seem to be usable for this.) Your best option may be to wrap a library implemented in a different language.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to format-preserving encryption.